# How can I check domain name availability using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns

How can I check to see if domain names are available using Javascript or JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery/js can only send HTTP requests. You'll need to use a whois service accessible via http. i.e. a script running on your server, or an API provided by someone else.

See
[Who provides a WHOIS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api)

Comment: The url is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably do it on the client side only, but if JS is your only option, you need to use a third party either through an API (such as http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/domain-availability.php) or for low volumes of lookups, you can just parse it from another site (e.g. http://whois.domaintools.com/whatever.com)

There are more integrated and much cleaner server side solutions if that's an option - [phpwhois](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/) for example is thorough and free.